# How to configure Galaxy Tab screen in Layout Editor

Tags: android, layout

I have a Galaxy Tab and I´m trying to configure the Android Layout Editor to have the same look that the real Galaxy Tab. I put the same configurations and the layouts are not equal yet. Has anyone configured it proper already?

My configs:
Resolution: 1024/600
DPI: 170
HDPI

Comment: Do you have the Galax Tab addon for the SDK? That might include a layout template.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the Galaxy Tab SDK AddOn ( http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do ). It includes a Galaxy Tab target that you can use to create a Galaxy Tab virtual device with the appropriate resolution and hardware buttons.

Comment: I already did, but I don´t want the virtual device, I wan´t to have also the Layout Editor.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration I did which gave me the best result is:

170 DPi

HDPI

Dimension: 1061/600 (My app don´t have the title bar, so I have to increase the height)

Portrait